# Character sum related to an elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $M$ be an odd prime and $\chi$ be a primitive character $\bmod M$. What is the evaluation of the character sum,
$$\sum_{b\bmod M}\chi(b)\left(\frac{b^2-1}{M}\right), $$
where $(\frac{.}{M})$ is the quadratic residue symbol.

Observation: When $\chi$ is the quadratic residue symbol, the above character sum equals $\#\{\text{ points on } y^2=x^3-x \text{ over } \mathbb{F}_M \} - M$.

Comment: Have you heard of the Jacobi sum of two characters? That is more or less what you have here.

Comment: Thanks @GalPorat, though it looks more like a Jacobi sum of three characters since $b^2-1 = (b-1)(b+1)$.